# networkx with node positions that change over time

Tags: python, networkx

I am a beginner with networkx(python), I want to draw an interactive graph with node positions that change over time. I know how to fix the node positions for my first graph, but then how can I update node positions? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not trivial to do so. Networkx is based on `matplotlib` scatter ([see code here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes)) for nodes and `LineCollection` for edges.

To create an animated graph, you should get your inspiration from [this matplotlib animated example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/animation/rain.html).

The basic stub should look like this:

```
# Create new Figure and an Axes which fills it.
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1), ax.set_xticks([])
ax.set_ylim(0, 1), ax.set_yticks([])

scat = nx.draw_nodes(G)

def update(frame_number):
    # TODO
    # Change node position (x, y) here
    scat.set_offsets(new_pos)

# Construct the animation, using the update function as the animation
# director.
animation = FuncAnimation(fig, update, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it doesn't work. It seems to me that the matplotlib animation function doesn't work for graphs. Am I wrong?